# LEFT JOIN com GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by

Estou usando PHP e MySQL, tenho duas tabelas no banco de dados:

```
POSTAGEM
id 
----
1

3

13

CURTIDA
id | id_usuario | id_postagem
-----------------------------
1  |     1      |     1

7  |     12     |     1
```

O que não consigo é o seguinte: quero dar um select nas postagens e ao lado dela dizer qntas curtidas cada uma tem, fiz assim:

```
SELECT postagem.id AS idPostagem, COUNT(curtida.id) AS curtidasTotais
FROM postagem 
LEFT JOIN curtida ON curtida.id_postagem = postagem.id
GROUP BY curtida.id_postagem
```

Mas ele acaba não listando direito as postagens que não tem curtida... nesse exemplo não lista a postagem 13 (que não tem curtida) mas lista a 3(que também não tem curtida)

Aqui vocês podem ver esse erro em ação: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c0d7c/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

o Problema é que você esta dando grup by pelo valor da tabela que esta selecionada pelo left join. Para acertar basta inverter:

```
SELECT postagem.id AS idPostagem,  COUNT(curtida.id) AS curtidasTotais
FROM postagem 
LEFT JOIN curtida ON postagem.id = curtida.id_postagem
GROUP BY postagem.id
```

Agrupando pelo id da tabela original.

Pode conferir o resultado aqui:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c0d7c/9/0

Answer (score 2):

Neste caso como você quer apenas a quantidade de curtidas você pode utilizar uma `subquery` para buscar a contagem:

```
SELECT p.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(1)
          FROM curtida c
         WHERE c.id_postagem = p.id) AS curtidas
  FROM postagem p
```

Veja funcionando no [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c0d7c/12).